# How to assign a custom icon to MaterialUI button's 'startIcon'?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

My current code is as below:

```
import {
  Button,
  Grid,
  Typography,
  } from '@material-ui/core';

import EditOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/EditOutlined';

<Grid item>
     <Button
        variant="outlined"
        className={classes.button}
        onClick={toggleState('showEdit')}
        startIcon={<EditOutlinedIcon />}
     >
     Edit
     </Button>
</Grid>
```

How can I assign a custom icon to `startIcon` instead of using `EditOutlinedIcon` that comes with material-ui?

**UPDATE:**

When tried with @Peter Ambruzs's answer below (with inline svg) it works, but when I try the same by linking the code to an icon stored in the src/assets folder only the file path is displayed on the button as below:

[image]

My code:

```
import {
  EditIcon,
} from '../../../assets/icons';

 <Grid item>
            <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={EditIcon}>
                   custom
            </Button>
 </Grid>
```

My icon is here:

[image]

index.js file:

```
export { default as EditIcon } from './edit.svg';
```

edit.svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{display:none;}
    .st1{display:inline;}
    .st2{opacity:0.5;}
    .st3{fill:#DEEACE;}
    .st4{fill:#71C6D8;}
    .st5{fill:none;stroke:#71C6D8;stroke-width:0.05;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st6{display:inline;fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st7{display:inline;fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st8{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st9{fill:#1E1E1C;}
    .st10{fill:#020203;}
    .st11{fill:#B2115B;}
</style>
<g id="Layer_1" class="st0">
    <g class="st1">
        <g>
            <g class="st2">
                <path class="st3" d="M0,0v32h32V0H0z M30,30H2V2h28V30z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st4" d="M29.8,6.2v19.6H2.2V6.2H29.8 M30,6H2v20h28V6L30,6z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <path class="st4" d="M21.8,10.21v11.6H10.2v-11.6H21.8 M22,10.01H10v12h12V10.01L22,10.01z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st4" d="M27.8,4.2v23.6H4.2V4.2H27.8 M28,4H4v24h24V4L28,4z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st4" d="M25.8,2.2v27.6H6.2V2.2H25.8 M26,2H6v28h20V2L26,2z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <path class="st4" d="M16,2.2c7.61,0,13.8,6.19,13.8,13.8S23.61,29.8,16,29.8S2.2,23.61,2.2,16S8.39,2.2,16,2.2 M16,2
                        C8.27,2,2,8.27,2,16c0,7.73,6.27,14,14,14s14-6.27,14-14C30,8.27,23.73,2,16,2L16,2z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st4" d="M31.8,0.2v31.6H0.2V0.2H31.8 M32,0H0v32h32V0L32,0z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="16" y2="0"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="20.29" y2="0"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="25.24" y2="0"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="32" y2="0"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="32" y2="6.76"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="32" y2="11.71"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="32" y2="16"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="32" y2="20.29"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="32" y2="25.24"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="32" y2="32"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="25.24" y2="32"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="20.29" y2="32"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="16" y2="32"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="11.71" y2="32"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="6.76" y2="32"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="0" y1="32" x2="16" y2="16"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="0" y1="25.24" x2="16" y2="16"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="0" y1="20.29" x2="16" y2="16"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="0" y1="16" x2="16" y2="16"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="0" y1="11.71" x2="16" y2="16"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="0" y2="6.76"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="0" y2="0"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="6.76" y2="0"/>
            <line class="st5" x1="16" y1="16" x2="11.71" y2="0"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <circle class="st5" cx="16" cy="16" r="12"/>
            <circle class="st5" cx="16" cy="16" r="10"/>
            <circle class="st5" cx="16" cy="16" r="8"/>
            <circle class="st5" cx="16" cy="16" r="6"/>
            <circle class="st5" cx="16" cy="16" r="4"/>
            <circle class="st5" cx="16" cy="16" r="2"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="earlier" class="st0">
</g>
<g id="Layer_2">
    <path class="st9" d="M26.25,9.66l-3.94-3.87c-0.39-0.38-1.01-0.38-1.4,0L5.75,20.74c-0.19,0.19-0.3,0.44-0.3,0.71v4.040.71v4.04
        c0,0.55,0.45,1,1,1h3.73c0.26,0,0.51-0.1,0.7-0.29l15.37-15.13c0.19-0.19,0.3-0.45,0.3-0.71C26.55,10.1,26.44,9.85,26.25,9.66z
         M9.77,24.5H7.45v-2.62l10.41-10.26l2.48,2.48L9.77,24.5z M21.77,12.69l-2.49-2.49l2.33-2.3l2.51,2.47L21.77,12.69z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What kind of icon do you want to use?

Comment: We have a custom svg file located at `src/assets/icons` that we want to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create an image with the svg as a source. Like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import EditOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/EditOutlined";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";

export default function App() {
  const svgIcon = (
    <Icon>
      <img alt="edit" src="edit.svg" />
    </Icon>
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid item>
        <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={svgIcon}>
          custom
        </Button>
        <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<EditOutlinedIcon />}>
          Edit
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-jepsen-eo3td

Comment: Many thanks for your kind response. When I try to link your sample to my custom icon inside the 'assets' folder, only the 'path' of the icon gets displayed on the icon instead of the image. I've updated my question with this info. Could you have a look at it? Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. The icon doesn't display nicely though probably due to the content of my svg file. I'll have to have a further look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I need add width style to img tag, to downscale svg icon. There small improve of Peter Ambruzs code.

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Button, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
    import EditOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/EditOutlined";
    import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";

    export default function App() {
  enter code hereconst svgIcon = (
    <Icon>
      <img alt="edit" src="edit.svg" style={{width: "100%"}}  />
    </Icon>
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid item>
        <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={svgIcon}>
          custom
        </Button>
        <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<EditOutlinedIcon />}>
          Edit
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to import your local svg in a different way to be a React Component.

```
import { ReactComponent as EditIcon} from '../../../assets/icons/edit.svg';
```

and then use it as a component.

```
<Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<EditIcon />} >
      Edit
</Button>
```